# Android Emulator does not show status bar

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

When I run my flutter projects on the android emulator it shows the error

```
System UI isn't responding
```

There are two options:

```
Close App
Wait
```

If I click on **Wait**, the error goes for a few moments but after a while, it shows again. And If Click on the **Close app**, the status bar is gone. Please watch the screenshot below for a better understanding.

[image]

Comment: try flutter clean and rebuild, also check if there any error with your code

Comment: also wrap `Scaffold` with `SafeArea()`, if haven't yet

Comment: Try this Go to Android studio then Open AVD select your device right click it and select wipe Data or cold boot and rerun your app

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil It worked, But I have to lose all data and it worked temporarily. I need a permanent solution. Thank you.